# Install DESeq2 on Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, r

I tried running the recommended [installation instructions](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html):

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
```

After an extremely long printout I observed this message.

```
Warning messages:
1: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘genefilter’ had non-zero exit status
2: In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘DESeq2’ had non-zero exit status
```

On Ubuntu I have found this issue as well, which has been reliabiably addressed by [this answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/installing-deseq2-in-ubuntu). But I have not been able to install the `libcurl-openssl` package on Arch.

How can I install DESeq2 on Archlinux?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful this might be now, but this might be an issue with R Studio's system dependancy on `gcc-fortran`. Try running:

```bash
sudo pacman -S gcc-fortran
```

This worked for me when I was running into the same issue.